# Same value increment counter start over again when a new value is encountered

Tags: perl, counter

I have this array:

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
BBB
BBB
BBB
```

What I want to do is have a counter that increments if encountered a same value but goes back to 1 when a new value is encountered. So the output would then be:

```
AAA 1
AAA 2
AAA 3
BBB 1
BBB 2
BBB 3
```

I currently have this code, but it just goes 1 all the way and does not increment and go back to 1 when a new value is encountered.

```perl
sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
}

my %fields = ( ID => 0, );

while ( my $line = <$inputFH> ) {

    chomp( $line );
    my @lineVal = split( ',', $line, -1 );

    #push all IDs to array
    push @IDs, $lineVal[ $SMfields{ID} ];

    #get unique IDs
    @uniqueID = uniq( @IDs );

    ###  PART WHERE I DO THE COUNTER ######
    foreach my $uID ( @uniqueID ) {
        my $row = 0
        if ( $lineVals[ $SMfields{SYMBOL} ] = $uID ) {
            $row++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe this line --- @uniqueID = uniq(@IDs); ---- is removing what you need to count.

Comment: The code you show doesn't compile. It is *essential* to show the exact code that is giving problems when you ask for help. You haven't even shown the part that generates the output; you must give us something that we can run that exhibits the problem you are having.

Comment: This looks like a scope issue. All of your `my` variables are within a scope that forces them to be reset every time you call the subroutine or loop through your UIDs. (ie. `my %seen` and `my $row` will both be reset each time you enter that scope.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown enough of your code to be able to say for certain what is wrong. This program produces the output that you require by keeping track of the contents of the preceding line and comparing after each read to see if it has changed

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $tag   = '';
my $count;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    $count = $tag ne $line ? 1 : $count + 1;
    print "$line $count\n";
    $tag = $line;
}

__DATA__
AAA
AAA
AAA
BBB
BBB
BBB
```

#### output

```
AAA 1
AAA 2
AAA 3
BBB 1
BBB 2
BBB 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a better candidate for awk than perl, but the key trick is to remember the last value and reset the counter when the current value doesn't equal the last value?

```
#!/bin/perl
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  if ($_ ne $last) {
    $last=$_;
    $ctr=1;
  } else {
    $ctr++;
  }
  print "$_ $ctr\n";
}
```

Which gives:

```
$perl t.pl < a
AAA 1
AAA 2
AAA 3
BBB 1
BBB 2
BBB 3
```